# Como retornar o ID de um registro logo após ele ser inserido?

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, jdbc

Estou fazendo uma aplicação Java em conjunto com um banco de dados MySQL e gostaria de saber qual seria o melhor comando para retornar um ID auto incremento do banco logo após o registro ser inserido.

Minha aplicação irá trabalhar com vários acessos simultâneos ao banco e gostaria de uma forma que não ocorra erros do tipo de retornar um ID errado que foi inserida por outro usuário.

Estou utiliza `JDBC` e recupero a conexão desta forma:

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/exemplows";
private static final String USER = "XXXXXXXX";
private static final String SENHA = "XXXXXXX";

public static Connection obtemConexao() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, SENHA);
}
```

Comment: Você está usando `JDBC` "puro" ou alguma outra coisa, como `JPA`/`Hibernate`?

Comment: private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/exemplows";
 private static final String USER = "XXXXXXXX";
 private static final String SENHA = "XXXXXXX";
 
 public static Connection obtemConexao() throws SQLException
 {
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return
    DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, SENHA);
 }

Comment: Minha conexão é essa

Comment: Certo, provavelmente está usando `PreparedStatement` então, já incluo uma resposta para você.

Comment: achei esse comando na internet ppst.getGeneratedKeys().getInt("idOrdemCompra"); mas ainda não testei, será que ele funciona sem risco de ocorrer um bug de id errado?

Comment: Sim, é meio isto. Veja se minha resposta lhe ajuda.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim, há como recuperar. Partindo de como você recupera a conexão é possível que você esteja usando algo desta forma para construir o *statement* e fazer o *insert*:

```
final String sql = "INSERT INTO minha_tabela(coluna_um, coluna_dois) VALUES(?, ?)";
final Connection conn = obtemConexao();
final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
// seta os valores dos parâmetros
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Basicamente o que você precisa fazer é alterar a chamada de [`#prepareStatement(sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)) para [`#prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Este [`#prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int)) criar um *statement* que tem a capacidade de recuperar dados gerados pelo banco, como ids auto incrementados. Para usar, você pode fazer algo desta forma:

```
final String sql = "INSERT INTO minha_tabela(coluna_um, coluna_dois) VALUES (?, ?);";
final Connection conn = obtemConexao();
final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
// seta os valores dos parâmetros
ps.executeUpdate();
final ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
    final int lastId = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Este exemplo considera que você possui apenas uma coluna "auto gerada" e recupera o valor dela. Você pode chamar também pelo nome, assim:

```
final int lastId = rs.getInt("id");
```

Caso exista mais de uma coluna "auto gerada" na sua tabela, todas elas serão retornadas.

Comment: Estou tendo uma exceção aqui no MySQL, ele insere o registro mas na hora de retornar o id ele fala que a coluna não foi encontrada, conferi aqui se eu digitei errado, mas não, esta correto , dei até um ctrl+c ctrl+v no nome LINK COM IMAGEM DO DEBUG http://postimg.org/image/rejapfqzz/

Comment: @user3777310 este erro é porque você não tem esta coluna na sua tabela. Ou, caso tenha, ele não é auto gerado. No `ResultSet` retornado só existem os que são, de alguma forma, auto gerados.

Comment: Depois de um tempo mexendo aqui consegui fazer funcionar, ao invés de colocar o nome da coluna eu coloquei a posição então ficou mais fácil, pois era só um coluna que eu estava procurando mesmo, valeu ai pela ajuda Bruno César

Comment: eu também não consegui passando o nome da coluna como argumento. Talvez seja o caso de editar essa resposta

Comment: @MicaelFerreira o funcionamento por coluna depende do driver JDBC, então, assim como diversos outras características da especificação, algumas coisas não funcionam dependendo do driver.

Answer (score 4):

Eu já fiz da seguinte forma:

```
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            novoId = resultSet.getInt("LAST_INSERT_ID()");
        }
```

Executando este código logo após a inserção será retornado o último id gerado.

Answer (score 1):

O key gerado no auto_increment não precisa ser retornado em um ResultSet,
Segue exemplo:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tabela1 (ID_CLIENTE,total) VALUES (?,?)";
        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, cliente.getID());
            stmt.setDouble(2, total);
            stmt.execute();
            sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @id";
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.execute();
            sql = "INSERT INTO tabela2 (ID_TABELA1,valor) VALUES (@id,?)";
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setDouble(1, valor);
            stmt.execute();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ValorClienteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        } finally {
            ConnectionFactoryMySQL.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);
        }
```

testado e funcionando.