# Como pegar id de elemento que acabou de ser inserido - JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

Como faço para pegar um `id` de um elemento que acabou de ser inserido no **Banco de Dados** no Java? Algo parecido como: `mysql_insert_id()` no `PHP`.

Comment: Você está utilizando JDBC com `PreparedStatement` e `ResultSet`? Ou está usando alguma outra API?

Comment: Qual é o banco de dados?

Comment: Se for com MySQL (eu não sei se todos os bancos são assim) tem a resposta no próprio site: [Como retornar o ID de um registro logo após ele ser inserido?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65736/como-retornar-o-id-de-um-registro-logo-ap%C3%B3s-ele-ser-inserido)

Comment: Se vc não descobrir maneira melhor,  em último caso pode fazer o insert com uma transação e um select id from tabela order by id desc limit 1;

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal, descobri que o Hibernate, através do persiste ou merge, já retorna um objeto preenchido com o ID do Banco. Desculpe a demora para postrar a solução! Obrigado a todos, sucesso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de uma `transaction`, logo após inserir no banco e antes de realizar o `commit`, você pode fazer `SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY id DESC` (SQL para Oracle). Essa consulta lhe retornará o ultimo `id` inserido.

O SQL pode variar conforme seu banco, mas a ideia é essa.

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal, descobri que o Hibernate, através do persiste ou merge, já retorna um objeto preenchido com o ID do Banco. Desculpe a demora para postrar a solução! Obrigado a todos, sucesso!